# I have an iOS app written in Objective-c and a Wordpress Website with WooCommerce. How can I connect them?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I built a website and set it up with the WooCommerce plugin to handle my eCommerce.  That system works great.

I built an iOS app that is not connected to my Wordpress site at all.  I am clearly a novice, but I am trying to understand how to connect these two systems.

Usernames/Passwords, Purchases, Shipping, etc....

Can anyone point me in the right direction of a solution, because I am coming up blank on my search. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1) Install one of the [plugins](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication) for Wordpress authentication. (P.S. I used basic authentication in the example below.)

Step 2) Go to WooCommerce > Settings > API > Keys/Apps, and add a new key and then generate API Key. It will create consumer_key and consumer_secret for you.

Step 3) Enable REST API in the WooCommerce settings. (To enable the REST API within WooCommerce, visit the WooCommerce > Settings > API tab and tick the Enable REST API checkbox.) [source](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/)

Step 4) I assume that you are developing an app with Swift. If so see the code below for getting user details and orders for example. Don't forget to include [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) framework in your project.

```
// to get user info
let plainString = "WP_username:WP_password" as NSString
let plainData = plainString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64String = plainData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))


let headers = [
    "Authorization": "Basic " + base64String
]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_envelope=1&context=embed", headers: headers)
    .responseJSON{ response in switch response.result {
    case .Success(let JSON):
        print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")

    case .Failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
}


// to get a customer's orders
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://yourwebsite.com/wc-api/v3/customers/USER_ID/orders", parameters:    
["consumer_key":"ck_XXX", "consumer_secret":"cs_XXX"])
         .responseJSON{ response in switch response.result {
            case .Success(let JSON):
                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                print(response)

            case .Failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
          }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I followed the steps exactly however, when I run the code i get a json response:  "oauth_Consumer_key parameter is missing"

Comment: Did you replace ck_XXX with your key and cs_XXX with your secret?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the WooCommerce REST API.  Sorry that I don't know if it offers everything you're looking for, but researching that might be a good starting point.

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't if this is what you want but you could just put the website in a web view