# WooCommerce user login

Tags: ios, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

How can I authenticate a user in WooCommerce? I'm able to create a user using woocommerce rest API (create a customer) but there are no documentation to make a user login with his username and password. 
Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand, authenticate where?

Comment: When trying to login in a user! I basically want to log the user into the application

Comment: Log them in where? In a browser? On server side? What for, what operations do you need to do on the customer's behalf? Please add more detail.

Comment: I need to log the customer in on an iOS mobile application. At present I can create a customer, view products, orders and product details. I stuck when I need the user to login so that the user can place the order

Comment: @Samarth Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37214547/1259775)